# Не могу авторизоваться на Gmail через IMAP, библиотека Limilabs

Tags: c#, google-chrome, консоль, авторизация, imap

Я к сожалению на данный момент не много знаю про IMAP. Но пытаюсь сейчас сделать авторизацию на gmail. Пишу код на c#, консольное приложение.

Вот код программы:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Imap imap = new Imap())
        {
            imap.ConnectSSL("google.com");
            try
            {
                imap.Login("delisuxa@gmail.com", "password");
                Console.WriteLine("Проверка пройдена");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка");
            }
        }
    }
```

Все пишеться в методе Main. Вместо пароля заранее поставил "password". А то мало что, вдруг кто небудь заберет у меня тестовый аккаунт.
Проблема в том что когда я запускаю программу, то у меня не чего на консоль не выводиться.
Даже сообщение "Ошибка", она тоже у меня не выводиться.

Можете мне подсказать что я не правильно делаю?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23375968/12888024

Comment: `Можете мне подсказать что я не правильно делаю?` - для начала, надо понять что такое IMAP, а не просто так бездумно настраивать фиг пойми что. Вот допустим, почему `imap.ConnectSSL("google.com");`? Почему тут указан именно этот адрес? Достаточно ведь открыть [документацию](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229) и увидеть там адрес `imap.gmail.com`, порт `993`, а также увидим, что IMAP включается в аккаунте. Вы это сделали все? Думаю нет, ибо `google.com`... Касательно ошибок - ну значит такая библиотека, где авторы их "проглатывают" а не выводят, думаю уже можно сделать выводы о ней.

Comment: Limilabs - платная библиотека, если вы ее купили, обратитесь к разработчику, у них есть техническая поддержка.

Comment: Здравствуйте @EvgeniyZ! Хорошо, спасибо за ответ. Если что, то уже подставлял "imap.gmail.com" и у меня вылизала ошибка "Этот хост неизвестен." Но видимо и правда что нужно было поставить порт. 
Так что попробую. Так же все в google настроил. Как написано в той документации. Если что, то опять по ней пройду.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо вам за ответ. Уже не раз мне помогали. Если что, то я ее скачал бесплатную. Если же будет потребность ее купить, то куплю. Но пока что не вижу разницы платной версии от бесплатной.

Comment: Попробуйте MailKit. Эту либу сами майки рекомендуют.

Comment: Здравствуйте @John. Хорошо, попробую данную библиотеку. На данный момент саму ошибку я исправил. Все еще использую библиотеку Limilabs. Только возникла еще одна проблема, с тем что у меня пишут неправильные данный для входа на аккаунт. Сам аккаунт я проверял и он хорошо работает. Что бы исправить первую ошибку я просто написал порт 993. 
imap.ConnectSSL("imap.gmail.com", 993);

Comment: А разрешили-ли вы доступ для небезопасных приложений (ваш скрипт) в разделе Безопасность аккаунта ?

Comment: Здравствуйте @c0ol! Если же я вас правильно понял, то я в gamil настройках, только включил imap.
Вот скриншот: https://pastenow.ru/06a7e68dcbffe52b18b4c40cec432e8c
Больше там не чего не трогал. Еще в самой документации написали как подключить imap. Я его подключил в своей программе. Вот ссылка на документацию: 
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229
К сожалению у меня все равно не чего не работает. А SMTP не подключал. Мне лишь просто нужно авторизоваться через gami. Но не получается. Сами данные от аккаунта верные.

Comment: @ZigDDa, еще разок перечитайте выше пост, можете загуглить - надо галку поставить. Вы разрешили своему скрипту доступ или нет ?